# Como fazer listagem crescente e decrescente em registros com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Minha tabela está da seguinte forma[image: imagem do painel de adminstracao]

Através do PHP, estou listando os registros do banco de dados MYSQL dentro de um LOOP WHILE.
Gostaria de saber como fazer para que, ao clicar em ID, ou, DATA, os dados sejam exibidos de forma crescente ou decrescente.

**SCRIPT PHP:**

```
<?php                    
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABELA ORDER BY id DESC";
$rs = mysqli_query($conecta,$strSQL); 
$error = mysqli_error($conecta);
if(!$error){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)):
?>
<ul class="lista-posts">       
   <li class="seleciona"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> " /></li>
    <li class="id"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></li>
    <li class="titulo"><?php echo '<a title="'.$row['titulo'].'" class="link-texto" href="artigo-'.$row['slug'].'">'.substr($row['titulo'], 0, 63).'</a>'; ?></li>
    <li class="data"><?php echo '<data class="data">'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['data'])).'</data>'; ?></li>
    <li class="data"><?php     
    if($row['id_categoria'] == 'faq') {
        $novoIdCategoria = str_replace("faq","duvidas-frequentes",$row['id_categoria']);
        echo '<a href="'.$novoIdCategoria.'.php">'.ucfirst("faq").'</a></data>'; 
    } else {
        echo '<a href="'.$row['id_categoria'].'.php">'.ucfirst($row['id_categoria']).'</a></data>'; 
    } ?></li>        
    <li class="gerenciar"><?php 
        echo '<a title="Ver" class="apagar" href="artigo-'.$row['slug'].'"><label class="icon-eye"></label></a>';
        echo '<a title="Editar" class="editar" href="edita.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><label class=" icon-pencil"></label></a>';?>         
    </li> 
</ul>    
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Desde já, grato!

Comment: Tem várias formas de fazer isso, uma seria usar algum grid js que faça a ordenação do itens outra é fazer um combo ou o link mesmo, quando clicado ele faria uma requisição ao php passado dois argumentos, por qual coluna deve ser ordenado e a orientação(crescente ou decrescente), por ser feito com ajax ou requisiçao php normal.

Comment: Fiquei confuso, como disse abaixo. A minha query padrão executa a ordenação dos registros de forma decrescente através do ID. Como devo fazer para que cada link dispare uma query diferente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você terá de executar a sua query novamente no click efetuando a troca do campo e da orientação da ordenação exemplo:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABELA ORDER BY id DESC";

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABELA ORDER BY id ASC";
```

Outro campo:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABELA ORDER BY outrocampo DESC";
```

Atualizando com uma forma mais completa de fazer:

Do lado esquerdo do link coloca uma seta pra cima e do lado direito do link coloca uma seta pra baixo.

AS SETAS SERÂO UM LINK QUE APONTARAO PARA A MESMA PÁGINA, POREM COM PARAMETROS QUE você USARÁ NO SELECT.

```
<a href="mesma_pagina.php?ordem=crescente&campo=data"> <img src="setapracima.png" /> </a>
 Data
<a href="mesma_pagina.php?ordem=decrescente&campo=data"> <img src="setaprabaixo.png" /> </a>
```

Quando você clicar pra cima, você vai colocar em ordem crescente seu Select ou seja, ASC
entao. vai ficar assim:

```
   if($_GET['ordem] == "crescente")
      $sql = 'select * from tabela order by '.$_GET['campo'].' asc'; # na verdade nem precisa por asc
   elseif($_GET['ordem'] == "decrescente")
      $sql = 'select * from tabela order by '.$_GET['campo'].' desc'; # precisa por desc
   else
      $sql = 'select * from tabela'; # vai entrar aqui da primeira vez que carregar a página.

$exe = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: E isso seria feito com condições? Se for, como eu devo passa-las? Eu admito que fiquei confuso.

Comment: @ThiagoBarros Depende o quanto você conhece de php, você poderia passar isso por parametro $_GET ou post e fazer essa tratativa quando montar a query.

Comment: E como ficaria cada link? até porque a query é executada na mesma pagina, então não sei a lógica para isso..

Comment: a lógica é que voce ira atualizar a pagina a cada link. é interessante voce estudar um pouco de php antes de fazer isso segue link para http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/comunicacao-entre-paginas-usando-o-metodo-get

Comment: É interessante explicar o downvote pois o mesmo responde a pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe, mas não fui eu quem apliquei o downvote. E pra falar a verdade, também não entendi o porque da pessoa aplica-la. Compreendo que sua resposta está correta, e entendi a query, o problema está no meu conhecimento em não saber aplicar de forma correta à meu script.

Comment: Se te ajudou marque como resolvido e faça uma pergunta de como utilizar GET no php.

Comment: Na minha visão, seria correto marcar como resolvido caso realmente eu tivesse resolvido o problema, até para que eu pudesse editar o post com a resposta. Mas se na sua visão já está resolvido, e você sendo experiente aqui no site, irei respeitar sua opinião.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33181/discussion-between-thiago-barros-and-otto).

Comment: @ThiagoBarros atualizei com uma resposta mais completa

Comment: Obrigado Otto! Agora creio que conseguirei adapta-lo as minhas necessidades.